# Can I set sobject id in a method?

Tags: apex, sobject

Apex code developers guide says

```
   "The ID of an sObject is a read-only value and can never be modified explicitly in Apex unless it is cleared during a clone operation, or is assigned with a constructor"
```

thinking this tried to assign the id for for an sobject Account in a method it found working. So I feel the documentation is wrong. Or is there any other views?
Below is my  method

```
   public void setAccountId()
   {
    Account a = new Account(id='0019000000sAr8H');
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigning the id in the constructor of the SObject does work. It is a standard technique to allow data to be updated without having to first query:

```
update new Account(
        Id = accountIdFromSomehwereOrOther,
        MyCustomField__c = 'New Value'
        );
```

The `setAccountId` method you include in your question will effectively do nothing as a local scope `Account` is being created and then not used for anything.

(If this code is called in a test, then with a hard-coded id that is already present in the org, you will have to resort the `SeeAllData=true` anti-pattern.)

Comment: Documentation says you can't set id no where apart from constuctor but I am able to set the id in a method which is my concern

Comment: @ShebinMathew The documentation perhaps isn't as clear as it could be; they mean it can be set in the constructor of the SObject (Account in your case). That constructor can be invoked anywhere in a class using the Account.

Comment: Yes me to conclude this documentation doen't seems clear

Answer (score 1):

Setting the ID in the account in your method will pass, and "run" but you will encounter an error should you then try to insert that account via DML as per below:

[image]

So whilst having the ID in your Account in memory might prove useful in some scenarios, you are not really setting the Salesforce ID (once the object *gets* to the Salesforce data layer).

Incidentally this line:

```
Account a = new Account(id='0019000000sAr8H');
```

IS the "constructor" for an Account object, and so it is perfectly valid as-per the documentation to set the Id here. Where this line then appears in your code is of no consequence to this rule.

Edit: from Keith's answer, I've always wondered what use this would have, and updating records without having to query sounds pretty plausible..!

Comment: I've added an example to clarify that its an update not an insert where setting the id is useful.

Comment: Cool. I have added a little bit to clarify what it means by constructor..